# How to click span class text through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, xpath-1.0

I want to click the text in the span class

```
<div class="u_pg _more_btn_wrapper" style=""> 
<a href="#" onclick="nclk(this, 'sis.moreb', '', '')" class="u_pg_btn _btn_more"> 
<div class="u_pg_wrap"> 
<span class="u_pg_area"> 
<div class="loading _more_btn_loading" style="display: none;"> 
<span class="load_img">로딩중..
</span> 
</div> 
<span class="u_pg_txt _more_txt">더보기</span> 
</span>
 </div>
 </a> 
</div>
```

to click the span class "u_pg_txt _more_txt">더보기 
I tried two different codes below;

```
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span/span[contains(.,'더보기')]").click()
#driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("더보기")).click();
```

and 
they didn't work
help me out..

Comment: Is that a complete HTML? It doesn't seem valid. The visible part, that is...

Comment: What does "they didn't work" mean? Are you getting errors? What errors are you getting? Add more details.

Answer (score -1):

Another way of creating the xpath -->

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class,'u_pg_txt')]").click()
```